# Can't get data from Google Datastore from Node.js

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I can't get data from the method `getuserpost`. The web page stucks and doesn't show anything.

The rest of the code works well adding and deleting data and then redirecting to the home page but that method does not show the JSON output. I have tried with `res.send` and `res.render` but nothing.

Does someone know what's wrong with this code?

```
app.get('/getuser', (req, res) => {
    res.render('getuser');
});
//DOESN'T WORK
app.post('/getuserpost', (req, res) => {
    const query = datastore.createQuery('usersTable').filter('girl', req.body.girl_field).order('timestamp', { descending: true }).limit(10);
    datastore.runQuery(query).then((results) => {
        const entities = results[0];
        res.json(entities[0]);
    });
});
```

This is the HTML for that method:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="/getuserpost/" method="POST">     
        <label for="girl_name">Enter girl: </label>
        <input id="girl_name" type="text" name="girl_field" value="Default girl for user">
        <input type="submit" value="OK">
    </form>
    <br>
    <a href="/home">Home</a>
    <br>
    <a href="/adduser">Add user</a>
    <br>
    <a href="/updateuser">Update user</a>
    <br>
    <a href="/deleteuser">Delete user</a>
    <br>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm using Google Datastore with Google App Engine.

Comment: Please specify error message or execution results,

Comment: I don't know how to see error logs in app engine

Comment: Go to logging and select your deployed app. Also, you can check network tab in the browser, to see what has been returned by the server.

Comment: When I press ok, it doen't do nothing. The wheel of charge in the expolorer is running and running without doing nothing

Comment: "Error: Unsupported field value, undefined, was provided"
I don't understand because I can add and delete but not read

Comment: Are you the developer of this app?

Comment: Yes. It's only a test for knowing the way datastore works in node js.
Create, update, read, and delete.
I have done the same with GO and it works

Comment: the error that you sent, it should contain the stack trace. It should point the error line number. And please, provide full source code of the node.js app.

Comment: Here is the full code:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=es#!topic/google-appengine/s2yARayn0Lw

Comment: In which line error occurred?

Comment: I have changed the version several times and the error is 23 hours ago. The version of that date was deleted

Comment: The recent errors are not showed in app engine

Comment: I need more specific error message in order to be able to help you. The line on which error happens required.

Comment: I'll redo all, delete the database and wait for the indexes.
Tomorrow I'll send you the line.
What version of GETUSERPOST in the code do you think is better?
Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 1):

I guess you missed operator option in filter.

```
.filter('girl', "=", req.body.girl_field)
```

Comment: I have tried that, but doesn't work. The delete method works and doesn't use that "=" sign.
I have deleted all old error messages in App Engine I have used the get user web several times but no new errors arise.
I have used "gcloud app deploy index.yaml" before using "gcloud app deploy" and neither.
I have seen the "Network" tab in the explorer and nothing is showed.

Comment: When I use Postman I receive this:

<html>
    <head>
        <title>502 Bad Gateway</title>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="white">
        <center>
            <h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1>
        </center>
        <hr>
        <center>nginx</center>
    </body>
</html>

Comment: operator is optional in case of `=`

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION FOR READING DATA FROM "DATASTORE" IN "APP ENGINE" USING "NODE JS":

```
app.get('/getuser', (req, res) => {
res.render('getuser');
});
//WORKS
app.post('/getuserpost', (req, res) => {
    const query = datastore.createQuery('usersData').filter('girl', 
req.body.girl_field);
    datastore.runQuery(query).then((results) => {
        const entities = results[0];
        datastore.get(entities[0][datastore.KEY], (err, entity) => {
            if (!err) {
                res.send(entity);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You are doing something wrong. Entities already should contains data. We've using such approach every where in our project. Did you logged what is inside entities?

Comment: You are right, the code works as well without the datastore.get() method.
The problem was all time the "const query" variable.
I got rid of the methods after "filter" in the query and the code worked perfect.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get('/getuser', (req, res) => {
res.render('getuser');
});
//WORKS
app.post('/getuserpost', (req, res) => {
    /*const query = datastore.createQuery('usersData').filter('girl', 
req.body.girl_field).order('timestamp', { descending: true }).limit(10);
    datastore.runQuery(query).then((results) => {
       const entities = results[0];
        datastore.get(entities[0][datastore.KEY], (err, entity)=>{
            if(!err){
                res.json(entity);
            }else{
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    });*/
    res.send("output");

});
```

The problem is with the code inside getuserpost, when I comment the code It works but when I delete res.send("output") and uncomment the code It stucks. 
This commented version doesn't work neither.
This delete method below works and its query works

```
app.get('/deleteuser', (req, res) => {
    res.render('deleteuser');
});
//WORKS
app.post('/deleteuserpost', (req, res) => {
    const query = datastore.createQuery('usersData').filter('car', req.body.car_field);
    datastore.runQuery(query).then((results) => {
        const entities = results[0];
        datastore.delete(entities[0][datastore.KEY], (err) => {
            if (!err) {
                res.redirect('/');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION FOR ADDING DATA FROM "DATASTORE" IN "APP ENGINE" USING "NODE JS":

```
//WORKS
app.post('/adduserpost', (req, res) => {

    const user = {
        timestamp: new Date,
        name: req.body.name_field,
        girl: req.body.girl_field,
        car: req.body.car_field
    }

    datastore.save({
        key: datastore.key('usersData'),
        data: user
    }).then(() => {
        res.redirect('/');
    }).catch((err) => {
        res.redirect('/');
    });

});
```

Comment: This is unbelievable. I am writing CRUD methods that work for me to help other people who see this in the future and I am penalized.
I quit

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION FOR UPDATING DATA FROM "DATASTORE" IN "APP ENGINE" USING "NODE JS":

```
//WORKS
app.post('/updateuserpost', (req, res) => {
    const query = datastore.createQuery('usersData').filter('car', req.body.car_field);
    datastore.runQuery(query).then((results) => {
        let entities = results[0];
        entities[0].car = req.body.new_car_field;
        const entity = {
            key: entities[0][datastore.KEY],
            data: entities[0],
          };

          datastore.update(entity).then(() => {
            res.redirect('/');
          });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> You need composite indexing for the fields `girl` and `timestamp`.
>   Docs on composite indexes [here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/indexes).

Your yaml file should contain the following

```
- kind: usersTable
  properties:
  - name: girl
  - name: timestamp
    direction: desc
```

To apply the composite indexes, run the following command

```
gcloud -q datastore create-indexes path/to/yaml/file
```